# Assigning Inline declared table to Field Symbols

Tags: abap, custom-data-type

There is an inline-declared table generated from a `SELECT` statement as below:

```
SELECT *
INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_result)
FROM scarr.
```

How can `lt_result` be assigned to a Field Symbol?

I tried the following way:

```
  FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_lt_result> TYPE ANY.

  LOOP AT lt_result ASSIGNING <fs_lt_result>.
```

But I'm not able to call any components in the field symbol inside the loop like:

```
WRITE / <fs_lt_result>-carrid.
```

(syntax error: `The data object "<FS_LT_RESULT>" does not have a structure and therefore does not have a component called "CARRID".`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inline declaration of a field symbol for an internal table in an ASSIGN statement and inline declaration of a field symbol for the rows of the table in a LOOP.

```
LOOP AT <lt_result> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line>).
  ...
ENDLOOP.
```

source: https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenfield-symbol_inline.htm

Comment: To answer the reason why you're "not able to call any components in the FS inside the loop like `<fs_lt_result>-base_unit`" (in fact it means that you get a syntax error at compile time), this is because you declared the field symbol TYPE ANY, the compiler assumes that the field symbol will reference a data object of any type at runtime, so mentioning the component BASE_UNIT is refused. 

If you don't use an inline declaration for the field symbol, another way is to declare: `FIELD-SYMBOLS <fs_lt_result> LIKE LINE OF lt_result.` (after the declaration of lt_result of course)

Answer (score 1):

You declared that the field symbol is of unknown type (`ANY`, i.e. the exact type is known only at run time), so the compiler can't be sure that the mentioned component (`CARRID`) exists, hence the syntax error.

If you want to mention a component statically, the compiler must be informed of the exact type (what components exist).

For instance, this would work:

```
SELECT *
    INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_result)
    FROM scarr.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_lt_result> TYPE scarr.

LOOP AT lt_result ASSIGNING <fs_lt_result>.
  WRITE / <fs_lt_result>-carrid.
ENDLOOP.
```

Or use the inline declaration of the field symbol as you proposed in your own answer/solution:

```
LOOP AT lt_result ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_lt_result>).
```

NB: if your internal table had a type decided at run time only, it would be impossible to indicate statically the component name and you'd need to refer to the component dynamically:

```
ASSIGN COMPONENT ('CARRID') OF STRUCTURE <fs_lt_result> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<field>).
IF sy-subrc = 0.
  WRITE / <field>.
ENDIF.
```

Answer (score -3):

EXAMPLE: 
FIELD SYMBOL :  TYPE VBAK.
DATA: ITAB TYPE TABLE OF VBAK .

SELECT * FROM VBAK INTO TABLE ITAB UP TO 10 ROWS.

LOOP AT ITAB ASSIGNING 
WRITE : / -VBELN . (WRITE WHICH OUTPUT YOU WANT TO DISPLAY)
ENDLOOP.

Comment: Hellow and welcome to SO, please consider this guideline to improve your answer [answer]